# Populating dropdown lists using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Total noob to ajax here, how close am I with this syntax? I want the second dropdown box to be dependent on the first drop down box. I know this can't be the easiest way to solve this problem so any help is appreciated. `acura.txt` is a text file with markup to make another dropdown list. Thanks for your help everyone!

**JavaScript:**

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("acura").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "acura.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="stateinjured">
    <option selected="selected">Select your state</option>
    <option id="acura" onClick="loadMXLDOC">Acura</option>
    <option id="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option id="audi">Audi</option>
    <option id="benz">Benz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you considered using an ajax framework such as jQuery or is this just for your own knowledge?

Comment: Faraway since you tagged it with jquery...

Comment: You've tagged it as jquery but dont' seem to have used it as far as I can see. If you are wanting a jquery way of doing this then there are much nicer ways (it has built in nice syntax for ajax calls). If you want to stick with non-jquery then you might want to take away that tag. :)

Comment: i know jQuery well enough to do some styling things with it, toggle visibilities, add properties, etc..but this is outside my scope so i tried to find some code online i could finagle.  didn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming the 'onClick="loadMXLDOC"' instead of 'loadXMLDOC' is just a typo in your demonstration and not in your original, but wanted to point it out to be safe.

Comment: just google it and you will get loads of examples

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work to stuff a `<select>` tag (with its own `<option>` contents, presumably) into the content of an `<option>` tag. That's what your code will attempt to do now.

This code here:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("acura").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
```

The element whose "id" value is "acura" is one of the `<option>` tags in the `<select>` on the page. Thus, if that response text is just a `<select>`, it's going to go in the wrong place.

Maybe you just want another `<span>` on the page, or something; it depends on what it's supposed to look like.

Another thing: you don't want to pick up the "click" event on the `<option>`. It's possible for an option to be selected (by the user) without any "clicks" taking place. Probably you should track the "change" event on the `<select>` tag, and check the value in the handler.

Comment: the look of the page isn't important to me right now, i'm just trying to figure out what the correct code is then go from there :).  all i really need it to do is select one of those states and populate it with the text file. i'll remove the select tags, thanks.

Comment: hm..not quite sure what you mean, (sorry <--noob). can you explain a little better?

Comment: Pointy is highlighting too separate problems.  First, you need to insert your new select menu in a different container outside of your first select menu, such as a div adjacent to it. Second, use an onChange event handler in your select tag instead of an onClick event handler in your option tag so that the function is called whether the menu item is selected with the mouse or the keyboard.  When the function in the onChange is called, check for the value of the selected option to see if you should create your second dropdown.

Comment: @braveowl well, it's not really just the "look" of the page.  It simply won't work to drop a new `<select>` element into the "innerHTML" of an `<option>` tag.  It makes no sense at all.

Comment: so i need to do something like <option id="acura" onChange="#acura">Acura</option> with the acura function being something like acura {$("#acura")xmlhttp.open("GET","acura.txt",true);
? is that close

Comment: No, that's not close.  You need to code something into your HTML that will serve as the target for the content you retrieve.  Think about what your page needs to look like *after* the content (the new `<select>` list) is fetched.

Comment: so i need to write the acura.txt into a separate div on the page...could i do <div id="secondropdown">acura.txt markup here</div> $("#acura").add("acura.txt")?

Comment: Yes, something like that.  `$('#seconddropdown').html(xmlhttp.responseText);`

Comment: thanks for the pointing in the general direction, i'm going to try this out! thanks again.